# password fetch using python

Tags: python, linux, passwords

```
import pwd
import operator

# Load all of the user data, sorted by username
all_user_data = pwd.getpwall()
interesting_users = sorted((u 
                            for u in all_user_data 
                            if not u.pw_name.startswith('_')),
                            key=operator.attrgetter('pw_name'))

# Find the longest lengths for a few fields
username_length = max(len(u.pw_name) for u in interesting_users) + 1
home_length = max(len(u.pw_dir) for u in interesting_users) + 1

# Print report headers
fmt = '%-*s %4s %-*s %s'
print fmt % (username_length, 'User', 
             'UID', 
             home_length, 'Home Dir', 
             'Description')
print '-' * username_length, '----', '-' * home_length, '-' * 30

# Print the data
for u in interesting_users:
    print fmt % (username_length, u.pw_name, 
                 u.pw_uid, 
                 home_length, u.pw_dir, 
                 u.pw_gecos)
```

the above program fetch password from linux password file,
i want to create the program which shows linux kernel file which maintain logs of user login.
how to get into the kernel please help.......

Comment: I formatted the code for you. Please look at the preview next time. And it's "kernel", not "kernal". BTW your question is not clear.

Comment: "how to get into the kernel please" -- like in ... Tron?

Comment: the code has no relevance to the question.

Comment: *linux kernel file which maintain logs of user login* huh?

Comment: i have modified question please have a look........

Comment: user login? that would be /var/log/wtmp for the last few days or /var/run/utmp for current logged in.. They're both in binary though, but read by commands `last` or `who` respectively.. now what's the plan?

Comment: @Alexander : the `subprocess` module? That's the preferred way to run commands in Python.

Comment: Sure, it's not like I was quizzing you or anything.. more so curious about what you're up to

Answer (score 1):

Look at wtmp and utmp. There are APIs - check man wtmp